# Triangles and Cubic Polynomials?

Tags: c++

Given 2 cubic equations of the form (A∗X^3+B∗X^2+C∗X)
find out how many obtuse triangles could be formed from the roots of the 2 equations.

Note that only positive roots could be a triangle side, so any triangle should be formed of 333 positive roots (sides).

Input Constraints:

1≤T≤10^6

(−4∗10^8)≤A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2≤(4∗10^8)

Format of the input file:
First line : T i.e number of testcases
For each testcase :
First line : Three space separated integers A1, B1 and C1 
Second line : Three space separated integers A2, B2 and C2.
[images for test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HoRP.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3zPv.png)

**My code is:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int* roots()
{   
long int a,b,c;
int *x=new int[2];
int determinant;
cin >> a >> b >> c;
 determinant = b*b - 4*a*c;

if (determinant > 0) {
    x[1] = (-b + sqrt(determinant)) / (2*a);
    x[0] = (-b - sqrt(determinant)) / (2*a);

}

else {
    x[1] = -b/(2*a);
    x[0]=x[1];
}

return x;
}


int main()
{int t;
int *a,*b,x,y,z,c,i;
  cin>>t;
 do{c=0;
    a=roots();
   b=roots(); 
   for(i=0;i<2;i++)
   {x=a[i]*a[i];
   y=b[i]*b[i];
   if(x!=0&&y!=0)
   {switch(i)
   {
       case 0:z=a[1]*a[1];

            if(((x+y)<z||y+z<x||x+z<y)&&z!=0)
                c++;
                z=b[1]*b[1];
                if(((x+y)<z||y+z<x||x+z<y)&&z!=0)
                c++;
                break;
        case 1:z=a[0]*a[0];

            if(((x+y)<z||y+z<x||x+z<y)&&z!=0)
                c++;
                z=b[0]*b[0];
                if(((x+y)<z||y+z<x||x+z<y)&&z!=0)
                c++;
                break;

   }
   }
   }

    cout<<c<<"\n";
    t--;
}while(t);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: My code is exceeding time limit

Comment: Mention that in your post. As it is there's not much we can do.

Comment: Could you also show some of the test cases?

Comment: Also, are you sure the roots should all be integers and not floating point?

Comment: I'have tried it for float values. Also i have inserted the images of testcase.

Comment: But my first issue is that time limit is exceeding

Comment: When you run it on the example does it print the sample output?

Comment: yes it s printing but the other cases are not satisfied